# Ajax send same value but different options in dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel-5

I have a users' data table and im trying to change role of them by populating roles from database to datatable. I use ajax to change the role and it works. but problem is value of selecting option from dropdown is not sent to database.

Herewith I attached my controller function view and ajax code.
Please advise me to solve this.

Controller:

```
public function changeRole(Request $request){
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $isAdmin = Input::get('isAdmin');
    User::findOrFail($id)->update(['isAdmin'=>$isAdmin]);
}
```

Ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').on('change' , function (event){
 id = $(this).data('id');
isAdmin = $('#role').val();
//alert(role);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: SITE_URL + '/changeRole/',

    data: {
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        'id': id,
        'isAdmin': isAdmin

    },
    cache: false,          
    success: function(data) {              
    toastr.success('Admin Role Successfully Changed ! ', 'Congratulations', {timeOut: 5000});
    //$('#example1').DataTable().ajax.reload();           
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {    
        console.log(jqXHR);
        toastr.error('Something Error !', 'Status not Changed!')
        },
    }); 
}); 
});
```

View :

```
<td>
    <form method="post">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <div class="form-group">                
         <select class="form-control" data-id="{{$user->id}}" id="role" name="role">
         <option value="0">Select a Role</option>
          @foreach ($roles as $role)
          <option @if($user->isAdmin==$role->id) selected @endif value="{{ $role->id }}">{{ $role->name }}</option>
          @endforeach
          </select>
       </div>  
    </form>          
  </td>
```

[Please see the user table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChkXO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't use `Input::get('id')` use `$request->id` and `$request->isAdmin`

Try `dd($request->all())` at the very first line of you `changeRole()` method and check if you are getting the correct values every time.

Don't use `$('select')` give your select some id and use it as `$('#myselect')`

add `var` before you variable in jquery like `var id=$()` to keep it in local scope.
for reference must read this : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-difference-between-global-and-local-Variables-in-JavaScript

Don't use `var id = $(this).data('id');` the `.data()` messes things up sometimes.

Use it as
`var id = $(this).attr('data-id');`

To get the value of selected roles use following:

`var isAdmin = $(this).children("option:selected").val();`

Hope this fixes many things.

Comment: Thank You and I will try this

Comment: var isAdmin = $(this).children("option:selected").val();  Wow. This is working.Thanks a lot